# A warning using the Comparable Interface

Tags: java

I have a class ArraySort with the following code

```
    private Comparable<Object> a[];
private int nElems;

public ArraySort(int length)
{
    this.a = new Comparable[length];
    this.nElems =0;
}
```

Why does Java issue a warning at this statement

```
this.a = new Comparable[length];
```

It issues the following warning

```
Type safety: The expression of type Comparable[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Comparable<Object>[]
```

I know its just a warning but i would love to know the reason

Thank you

Comment: It's a bad idea to use arrays of generic types.

Comment: You're declaring a `Comparable<Object>[]` and then instantiating it as a `Comparable[]`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Have you thought about making this a generic class?  I think it would work more smoothly that way.

Comment: no such thing as *just a warning*, warnings are just that they are warning you that you made a mistake, they are not for decoration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Java does not support arrays of generic objects. Specifically, this is what you would want to write, but **the code below will not compile**:

```
this.a = new Comparable<Object>[length]; // <<== Does not compile!!!
```

A simple fix for this is switching to `List<Comparable<Object>>`: there is no loss of efficiency, and the compiler would be able to do the type checking for you:

```
private List<Comparable<Object>> a;
...
this.a = new ArrayList<Comparable<Object>>(length);
```